# tracking a simple camera movement

Tags: tracking

I'm new to Blender and am trying to track a very simple camera movement : I'm moving my camera from down to up, along a straight line.

I'm using a DJI Osmo camera, so that I get a stabilized image.

I've been able to do put several tracking markers which seem fine.

[image: bottom position]
I know in a ideal world I should put some specific markers on the road, but as there are always some cars using it, I won't have a chance to do that.

As I said, the camera movement is very simple : from the bottom position, I move to the top position along a straigt vertical line.

[image: up position]

When solving, I put 20mm for camera lens (dji osmo specifications) and 6.16mm for sensor width (again, from osmo specs).

According to many tutorials I've seen/read, I check `keyframe` and select `refine focal length, K1, K2`.

[image]

I thought I had all I need to get a good tracking result, but to my surprise, Blender goes all wrong !

I get a solve error of 3.6 (suprisingly, it seems each time a click on `Solve camera motion`I get different results). The lens focal is changed to 150.50mm (!?!), K1 to -488 and K2 to 326227 (!!!).

Is there something specific I should do for tracking such camera movement ?

I've been able to track sucessfully much more complex movements, and have no clues why I'm having such a hard time for this one.